# Custom parameters in stripe redirect url

Tags: php, stripe-payments

How to add custom parameters in stripe redirect URLs.
My code is

```
$authorize_request_body = array(
      'response_type' => 'code',
      'scope' => 'read_write',
      'client_id' => $stripe_client_id,
      'entity_id' => $entity_id,
);
$url = AUTHORIZE_URI . '?' . http_build_query($authorize_request_body);
echo "<a href='$url' class='btn btn-primary'>Connect with Stripe</a>";
```

I want to get dynamically 'entity_id' in redirect URLs
Is that possible?

Comment: I got answer from  here : https://support.stripe.com/questions/can-i-dynamically-set-the-redirect-url-for-my-connect-application

Comment: can you please let me know how did you accomplish it?